# How do I put apostrophes in a string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

I have a widestring say StringABC
I have an array say ArrayABC, elements of this array are

```
ArrayABC[0]='A';
ArrayABC[1]='B';
ArrayABC[2]='C';
```

Now I have to make `stringABC` as 
`StringABC := ''A','B','C'';`

I am trying to do this like

```
StringABC := '';
for (i:=0 to 2) do
begin
StringABC := StringABC + ArrayABC[i] + ',';
if i = 2
stringABC := StringABC + ArrayABC[i];
end
```

I am getting result as `stringABC = 'A,B,C'` but not `''A','B','C''` 
What should I improve in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringABC := '';
for (i:=0 to 2) do
begin
StringABC := StringABC + '''' + ArrayABC[i] + ''',';
if i = 2
stringABC := StringABC + '''' + ArrayABC[i] + '''';
end
```

Although I would just concatenate with the comma for all i, then al the end remove the final comma.

Comment: You can use `#39` or `#$27` instead of `''''`;

Comment: @Remy or make a named constant. I don't see #-literals easier to read or understand than 4x' sequence :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
Const
  StringArray:Array[7..11] of String=('A','B','C','D','E');

Function GetQuotedStringArray(const a:Array of String) : String;

var
 i:Integer;

 Function GetComma:String;
  begin
    if i <> High(a) then 
     Result :=',' else Result :='';
  end;

begin
  for I := Low(a) to High(a) do 
   Result := Result + QuotedStr(a[i]) + GetComma;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Showmessage(GetQuotedStringArray(StringArray));
end;
```

Comment: Oh and I usually simply add the separator unconditionally and at the end do `Result := SetLength(Result, Length(Result) - Length(Separator));`

Comment: @MarjanVenema The setlenght variant is widespread in in my code too;-)

Comment: So much better for my eyes :)

Answer (score 2):

One other alternative:

```
const
  StringArray:Array[7..11] of String=('A','B','C','D','E');

function GetQuotedStringArray(const a:Array of String): String;
var
  i: Integer;
  ComStrings: TStringList; 
begin
  ComStrings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ComStrings.QuoteChar := '''';

    for i := low(a) to high(a) do
      ComStrings.Add(a[i]);

    Result := ComStrings.CommaText;
  finally
    ComStrings.Free;
  end;
end;
```